# parser datetime via tsql

Tags: t-sql

Update List
set Date = "2009-07-21T19:00:40"

sql server doesn't recognize this format. is there a conversion function

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CAST and CONVERT](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ca-co_1.htm). But maybe you must replace the 'T' with a space, before you can convert it. (There are also string manipulation functions available.)

Answer (score 1):

Worked just fine for me (SQL Express 2005) except for the double quotes (which SQL Server assumed was a column delimiter); is that what's throwing the error?  Thanks for the sample code, but can you produce the actual error?

In other words,

> DECLARE @List TABLE ( [date] DATETIME
>   )
>
> INSERT  INTO @List
>           SELECT  GETUTCDATE()
>
> UPDATE  @List SET     Date =
>   "2009-07-21T19:00:40"

produces

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Invalid column name
>   '2009-07-21T19:00:40'.

Whereas

> DECLARE @List TABLE ( [date] DATETIME
>   )
>
> INSERT  INTO @List
>           SELECT  GETUTCDATE()
>
> UPDATE  @List SET     Date =
>   '2009-07-21T19:00:40'

runs successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE List SET Date = '2009/07/21 19:00:40'
```

Comment: Needless to say, you should not use reserved words for object names.

Answer (score 0):

Even worked for me too(2005 & 2008)..

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ( [date] DATETIME )
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT getdate()
select * from @tbl

UPDATE @tbl SET Date = '2009-07-21T19:00:40'
select * from @tbl
```

However, just give a shot with [DATEFORMAT COMMAND](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/28/sql-server-introduction-and-example-for-dateformat-command/)

Something like this

```
**SET DATEFORMAT dmy**

DECLARE @tbl TABLE ( [date] DATETIME )
INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT getdate()
select * from @tbl

UPDATE @tbl SET Date = '2009-07-21T19:00:40'
select * from @tbl
```